# solve merge conflicts in Xcode like VScode

Tags: xcode, visual-studio-code, merge-conflict-resolution

I have a question about solving merge conflicts in the Xcode project. I used to write JS in VScode and at that period I can just select either "accept incoming changes" or "keep original" (something like that). But I don't see that kind of stuff in Xcode, and I guess I have to manually delete the code which I don't need from the .siwft file.

So is there a tool like VScode's "accept incoming changes" and "keep original" stuff in Xcode? and also how other people solve the conflicts in Xcode? (I did a research a little but some people were doing it in the terminal, but not sure...)

Answer (score 0):

I normally use [Fork](https://fork.dev) to handle most git actions. It has also an UI for conflict resolutions and all changes will be reflected in Xcode immediately.